# SSRS : Argument 'VarExpr' is not a valid value

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am trying to calculate Month Name based on the Datepart calculation in SSRS.This code is working but with a warning..

```
=Switch(DATEPART(DateInterval.Month,Fields!TRANSACTION_DATE.Value)=12,"December",
DATEPART(DateInterval.Month,Fields!TRANSACTION_DATE.Value)=11,"November",
DATEPART(DateInterval.Month,Fields!TRANSACTION_DATE.Value)=10,"October",
DATEPART(DateInterval.Month,Fields!TRANSACTION_DATE.Value)=9,"September",
DATEPART(DateInterval.Month,Fields!TRANSACTION_DATE.Value)=8,"August",
DATEPART(DateInterval.Month,Fields!TRANSACTION_DATE.Value)=7,"July",
DATEPART(DateInterval.Month,Fields!TRANSACTION_DATE.Value)=6,"June",
DATEPART(DateInterval.Month,Fields!TRANSACTION_DATE.Value)=5,"May",
DATEPART(DateInterval.Month,Fields!TRANSACTION_DATE.Value)=4,"April",
DATEPART(DateInterval.Month,Fields!TRANSACTION_DATE.Value)=3,"March",
DATEPART(DateInterval.Month,Fields!TRANSACTION_DATE.Value)=2,"February",
DATEPART(DateInterval.Month,Fields!TRANSACTION_DATE.Value)=1,"January")
```

Warning :

```
[rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the field ‘MONTH_NAME’ contains an error: Argument 'VarExpr' is not a valid value.
```

Please suggest how to remove this error.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your expression, you should be able to use a much simpler expression with different date functions:

```
=MonthName(Month(Fields!TRANSACTION_DATE.Value))
```

Comment: Did this help at all?